# Determine which fragment of an OR regex matched with the string

Tags: python, regex, string

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "These are the words in a sentence"
>>> regex = re.compile('are|words')
>>> [m.start(0) for m in re.finditer(regex,s)]
[6, 14]
```

Is it possible to get the information that `are` matched at index `[6]`, and `words` matched at index `[14]`, without doing any extra string operations? Maybe like looping and finding each fragment of the regex at these returned indices, i.e. `6` and `14`.

Is there a direct way in regular expressions to know which fragment of an OR-based regex has matched?

Comment: map using `re.findall` as :- http://ideone.com/KojFuX

Comment: Could you please clarify? What is the use case? I think you want to get  a groupdict with named capture groups. Check [this demo](https://ideone.com/6sHHwB).

Comment: What is the output you are expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using [`re.MatchObject.group`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group)

From the documentation

> Returns one or more subgroups of the match. **If there is a single argument, the result is a single string**

(emphasis mine)

The code can be written as

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "These are the words in a sentence"
>>> regex = re.compile('are|words')
>>> [(m.start(0),m.group()) for m in re.finditer(regex,s)]
[(6, 'are'), (14, 'words')]
```

Comment: that's pretty simple..i made it more complicated

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
print([(re.findall(regex,s)[i], m.start(0)) for i,m in enumerate(re.finditer(regex,s))])
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/KojFuX)**